# Include more times a class in various files in C++

Tags: c++, include, declaration

I have 4 classes:
Server.cpp Logger.cpp Util.cpp Crypto.cpp

The class Server use the object Util.
The program works fine, but now I need to use the object Util also in the class Logger.
But when I put in the code #include "Util.cpp" g++ give me an error because I cannot call again the object.
Eclipse told me about the "redefinition" and "previous declaration" of class Util.

How can I solve this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: You have to include your code only once. You could add this to the top of your headers: `#pragma once`

Comment: Code should never be included (unless it's templates, but that doesn't seem to be the case here)! Always only include header files with the declarations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You should not include the source cpp files in to another cpp file.**
This basically violates the **[One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)** resulting in redefinition errors.

Include the header file which has the definiition of `Util` class in whichever class you want to create its objects.

Basically, Your code should be organized in this fashion(exception: Templatized code):

**Util.h**     -----------> Contains Definition of class `Util` acts as **Interface**
**Util.cpp**   -----------> Contains Implementation of class `Util` acts as **Implementation**

Here on whenever you want to create an object of class `Util` in any of the cpp files you include `Util.h` in that cpp file so the compiler knows the definition of class `Util`.

For ex:
`Server.cpp` wants to create an object of `Util` then your `Server.cpp` should include `Util.h` as:

```
#include "Util.h"
```

Also, don't forget to add **[Include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)** to your header files.

If the usage of `Util` by another source/header file is limited to creating a pointer to `Util` then you do not need to include the header file, You only need to **[Forward declare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)** the `Util` class.

Comment: Ok I got it.
But in my case, in Logger.h I need to create the object Util to use it in Util.cpp.
How is possibile?

Comment: @user1056635: Include `Util.h` in your `Logger.h`, I have explained the same in above answer,So If you are asking this Question I don't think you understood my answer.Please read it carefully and **understand** it,If you don't undestand something **ask**.

Answer (score 1):

You should enter only the header file, for example `Util.h`, not the .cpp files. Also, make sure you're using include guards. If the compiler gives you an error for multiple definitions, probably you missed include guards.

Answer (score 0):

**You declare your classes in `.h` files (or `.hpp`) and put implementation in `.cpp' files.**

You only include `.h`/`.hpp` files in other `.h`/`.hpp` or `.cpp` files, you never include `.cpp` files.

Make sure that every header file has guard to prevent from multiple inclusion, first line of header file `.h`/`.hpp` should be:

```
#pragma once
```